# How to convert object to string javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

I have an object that looks like this.

```
Object {Dry Aged Ribeye(medium): "1"
     , Dry Aged Ribeye(rare): "1"
     , Dry Aged Ribeye(well): "1"
     , favorite_tables: "{"dc76e9f0c0006e8f919e0c515c66dbba3982f785":[]}"
}
```

I wish to insert this to mysql in single column as is. If I try to insert it, it just says [object Object]. I tried to make it into string by JSON.stringify, Array.join() but no luck.

Help me convert this object into string.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far in JS ?

Comment: What is the SQL query you're using? Can you post the code that you have?

Comment: Not sure if that Object you posted above is verbatim to what you're actually using, but that is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Your object is not a valid JSON. That is why you cannot stringify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem on creating your JSON object, specifically the way you created your keys. You have to enclose it within quotation marks (or might I say stringify it).

```
var obj = {
    'Dry Aged Ribeye(medium)': "1"
    , 'Dry Aged Ribeye(rare)': "1"
    , 'Dry Aged Ribeye(well)': "1"
    , 'favorite_tables' : {"dc76e9f0c0006e8f919e0c515c66dbba3982f785":[]}
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it will work with your object as its keys are invalid, but you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify/) for converting an object to a string

```
var obj = {foo:'bar'};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have spaces in your keys then you must surround them with quotes.

```
var myObject ={"Dry Aged Ribeye(medium)": "1", 
  "Dry Aged Ribeye(rare)": "1", 
  "Dry Aged Ribeye(well)": "1", 
  "favorite_tables": "{'dc76e9f0c0006e8f919e0c515c66dbba3982f785':[]}"
}
```

I also replaced the double quotes in favorite_tables with single quotes.  Alternatively you could escape them with \"

With these changes then JSON.stringify should work